# JSON to POJO null check for fields

Tags: java, json, groovy, nullpointerexception

I have a very large complex JSON and I'm mapping this to a simple POJO (with only the required fields). In groovy JSON is interpreted as Map.

```
MyObject build(Map<String, Object> payload){

...
    o.name = payload.a.b.name
    o.gender = payload.c.d.e.gender

return o
}
```

The fields are optional and throws NullPointerException when not present. How to map to "" without putting try-catch for each line? My be straight forward but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would combine the *safe navigation* operator and the *elvis* operator.

If this throws while walking down the payload:

```
o.gender = payload.c.d.e.gender
```

Change it to:

```
o.gender = payload?.c?.d?.e?.gender ?: Gender.UNSET
```

(or if a `null` is fine, then leave out the `?:...` part)